# How to sign a Gnosis-Safe transaction via Argent wallet + Wallet-Connect

Tags: gnosis-safe, eip-1271

I'm trying to support Argent wallet signing (contract wallet / compatible EIP-1271) through Wallet-Connect.

Let's say I have a Gnosis-Safe with the following setup: `(owners: [argent-contract-addr], threshold: 1)`.

I'm able to obtain a signature of my transaction's `txhash` from Argent via Wallet-Connect, but this signature is signed by `argent-eoa-addr` controlling `argent-contract-addr`. Given Gnosis-Safe is compatible with EIP-1271 as well as [Argent wallet](https://docs.argent.xyz/wallet-connect-and-argent) that provides `isValidSignature`, it should be possible.

How can adjust this signature to be understood by the Safe as a contract signature?
From the safe's code, it looks like I should modify `v -> 0x00` but it seems that's not just it when I look [at the contract code](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L257-L285).

[image]

I'm also trying to understand [this test](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/186a21a74b327f17fc41217a927dea7064f74604/tests_deprecated/gnosisSafeNestedSafes.js#L49-L103) but it's not yet clear. Is there any documentation on how to build contract signatures compatible with Safe?

Comment: What problems do you run into when adjusting V in argent's signature?

Comment: `Invalid owner provided`

Comment: Check https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/signatures#contract-signature-eip-1271, but you might still run into issues with eip1271, as the Safe contract uses the a legacy version

Comment: Thanks @Richard, I will give a try

Answer (score 3):

To encode an EIP-1271 signature you would take the data returned by your signature function (for Argent this should be the data returned by `eth_sign` when connected via WalletConnect) and encode it with 2 parts.

The first part contains the address of the owner and the type. This is encoded as `0x<left-padded-owner-address><left-padded-data-position><type-0>`.

And the second part is the data.

If you have a Safe where the only owner would be an Argent wallet (e.g. `0xfBfe33a4462Ff0Bd86730499f65eBF7466914519`) the signature bytes would look the following.

```
// Prefix
0x 
// Owner address: 0xfBfe33a4462Ff0Bd86730499f65eBF7466914519
000000000000000000000000fBfe33a4462Ff0Bd86730499f65eBF7466914519
// Data offset: 65 bytes (32 bytes for each r and s and 1 byte for v)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041 
// Type
00
// Signature data returned by `eth_sign`
bde0b9f486b1960454e326375d0b1680243e031fd4fb3f070d9a3ef9871ccfd5
7d1a653cffb6321f889169f08e548684e005f2b0c3a6c06fba4c4a68f5e00624
1c
```

More details at: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/signatures#contract-signature-eip-1271

Comment: Thanks Richard for the explanation, it makes more sense.
However, I'm getting the following exception `Fail with error 'Invalid contract signature location: data not complete'` (GS023) for the following signature `0x0000000000000000000000002ac922cec780521f8ffab57d26b407936c352b820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041003f65cc85fb5c5d059c1af0f716dec562bcab3d828bdb7dc91c059f4604413ce82999e73c6e971ff340f298cd1cd34272545c32c78b0a3e848dbebd48a0f96ed31c` (txhash -> `0x49dfb17562ad7c0f0a55d46d4d1fec260fc9e95c29beadb5f4f75151a32ae1f3`

Comment: Ohh yeah mistake ob my side you need to include the length of the data