# How to create/propose a gnosis safe transaction from another smart contract

Tags: gnosis-safe

To preface, I'm super new to Solidity, so the answer might be super simple.

I've created a gnosis safe where 2/3 owners need to approve. I have a basic smart contract where I want to call a function I've defined called `sendToUser`... this function should propose a safe transaction ... do I just need to inherit the `execTransaction` here then I can use the function in my smart contract? https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol

Comment: researching this as well, did you make some progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To interact with another smart contract you need to declare an interface:

```
interface ICounter {
    function count() external view returns (uint);

    function increment() external;
}

contract MyContract {
    function incrementCounter(address _counter) external {
        ICounter(_counter).increment();
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint) {
        return ICounter(_counter).count();
    }
}
```

2. Proposing a Safe transaction. I assume that by proposing, you mean signing a transaction and sending it to the Safe Transaction service. To propose a safe transaction, your contract needs to implement the signature validation function defined in [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271). How to generate a smart contract signature for Gnosis Safe contract is described here: [How to sign a Gnosis-Safe transaction via Argent wallet + Wallet-Connect](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123087/how-to-sign-a-gnosis-safe-transaction-via-argent-wallet-wallet-connect)

Answer (score 0):

I found this material very helpful

https://medium.com/gauntlet-networks/multisig-transactions-with-gnosis-safe-f5dbe67c1c2d

The idea is roughly as follows:

- Setup a gnosis-safe and add signers
- Create your custom contract. Decorate any function that needs to be only executable by the multisig with `onlyOwner` ( you can use openzepellin's Ownable.sol)
- Deploy your custom smart-contract, transfer its ownership to the multisig address.
- Execute the function calls via gnosis-safe ui, or directly against the deployed multisig onchain via smartcontract calls.